# Custom Validation on Model in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to validate view model overriding ValidationAttribute.

1. Validation is working fine but when I try to display it using below

   @Html.ValidationSummary("ViewModel")

   **Output:** ViewModel ******Custom Error message*******

   How to remove "ViewModel" from it.
2. "IsValid" method of "ValidationAttribute" class is getting called twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how do you write your custom model validation error message in the first place?

If it is property-related, it should be added as this:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("PropertyName", "Custom Error message");
```

Then, in your view, you can display the message through:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.PropertyName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true);
```

Comment: Actually error msgs are attached with form-fields. I am using validationsummary only for exception messages.